# How to send report via email monthly automatically in asp .net

Tags: asp.net

can any one send me solution on this problem . Here i want to send crystal report that is automatically generated and attach to mail . Here report can be generated monthly automatically with asp .net along with c# Lang. Send me solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried using Windows Services (Background Process)?

Comment: Both Peyton and Sai are right you need to use windows Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the any of the following:

```
1. set "windows task scheduler" to schedule an .vbs file that triggers an "asp.net page or webservice" to run and do your logic once in a month (Recommended).

2. Create a "windows service" project and set a timer within its onstart event.(windows service creation only available in professional/Ultimate versions of visual studio, but editing and compilation can be done in other versions)
```

### Since the logic should be done once in a month the **step 1** is recommended.

Please see the steps to create the .vbs file that calls your asp.net page/web service

1. Open notepad and copy the following code in it and save

   ```
   'Declare variables
   Dim objRequest
   Dim URL

   Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

   'Put together the URL link appending the Variables.
   URL = "http://computerName/VirtualDirectoryName/Logic.aspx"

   'Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
   objRequest.open "POST", URL , false

   'Send the HTML Request
   objRequest.Send

   'Set the object to nothing
   Set objRequest = Nothing
   ```

   1. change the extension from ".txt" to ".vbs"
   2. Create a new schedule in windows "Task Scheduler" and point the newly created sample.vbs file which will call the page where your logic is written (http://computerName/VirtualDirectoryName/Logic.aspx) and edit the settings to run once in a month.

Comment: I'll second the recommendation to use windows task scheduler. I'd go one step further and generate the reports using a (scheduled) console app or SQL Reporting Services.

Comment: can you send me any code that how to make windows services and how can i use in my project .I never use windows services before.

Comment: @lucky jain, since you triggers your action after a long period (once in a month) it is better to use windows task scheduler. Usually windows services are used for shorter period triggers (atleast once in a day).

Comment: @lucky jain, I've updated my answer with some steps to implement scheduling using windows task scheduler.

Comment: @lucky jain, Do not misunderstood the code i gave. It is vb script code used to call your asp.net page where you have to do the report generation logic. Just edit the "URL = "http://computerName/VirtualDirectoryName/Logic.aspx"" part of it and place it inside root folder. Each time when you trigger the .vbs file your page will be executed. To trigger the .vbs file add a new schedule in windows task scheduler and point the sample.vbs file and set the time schedule to execute.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above recommendations to use a Scheduled task (console app), but nobody has mentioned that you cannot schedule a web-page to be executed on a schedule like that without an external utility that basically schedules an HTTP-request. Not to mention that a report that needs to be executed monthly typically cannot finish executing before the limited (default) response timeout anyways. That's what it's a bad idea. However, in the interest of answering the question, I will say that you can write a simple VBS or C#(.NET) console app to make an HttpRequest to your webserver and send the result in an email. Then add that console app to the windows task scheduler to execute monthly. Now your ASP.NET application is sending monthly emails. Don't forget that your C# console application will need to deal with login and authentication (if necessary).

The alternative is to (unreliably) create a timer (background process) within your global.asa (Application scope) when the [HttpApplication.Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.init.aspx) method is called. The reason this is unreliable is that the Application object can be recycled at any time, and may not even be running if no requests have been made to this application in a while. In addition, if you have a web-farm environment, each server (and each server process in a web-garden scenario) runs its own instance of your HtppApplication object. They may even be overlapping within the same process space while one is being garbage collected.

Comment: I'll add my two cents about avoiding the use of timers in a web application.  One of my projects did this, in order to simplify deployment, but the schedule tasks were very unreliable - sometimes multiple instances running at once, sometimes no instances running at all.  This meant that they failed to reliably perform their tasks - when multiple instances ran, dead-locks and time-outs would occur on the database.  Of course, when they did not run at all, nothing got done.

Answer (score 0):

> To generate monthly automatically use
>   Windows Services